# Paint tool not working (sculpt mode, blender 3.6)

Tags: texture-painting, sculpt, sculpt-mode

I have recently stated learning blender and I am working on a character. I tried sculpting in sculpt mode and all tools have been working fine except paint. I'm not able to paint anything and I cant seem to figure out why. Help!

files-https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14iEkmDhr5VS3WsAlsjtO_xvwZBpoKITJ?usp=drive_link

[image]

Comment: Your question title says you're using Blender 3.6, but the image shows 3.5.0. 3.6.2 is working fine here as is 3.5.1, both with default settings so you may need to share your file so that we can have a look. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ if it's smaller than 30Meg following the instructions there to copy the link to this question into the field on that page and it will then appear in your question above.

Comment: Just one thought, if you are talking about not being able to see what you've painted when you switch out of sculpt mode into rendered view, see [this](https://youtu.be/pz2ONQ-aFTI?t=252) part of a tutorial which explains the whole process.

Comment: I have added a screen recording and the blend file to this folder.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14iEkmDhr5VS3WsAlsjtO_xvwZBpoKITJ?usp=drive_link
thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with sculpting, but playing around with your model, try the Mask > Clear Mask menu (Alt-M). That seems to let you paint on your model ok.

Comment: that solved it, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! I've learnt something too! :^)